# getting error "expect: spawn id exp4 not open" while trying to grep

Tags: bash, expect

Im trying to compile a script that establishes an ssh connecting with a remote machine and searches multiple log files for error messages, my current code is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <<-EOF > /home/file
set timeout 3
spawn ssh -oPort=port ip zgrep "error" /dir/dir/file.gz.\[54321\]
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "*password: " { send "password\r" }
expect "*#" { send "exit\r" }
EOF
expect <<-EOF >> /home/file
set timeout 3
spawn ssh -oPort=port ip zgrep "error" /dir/dir/file1.gz.\[54321\]
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "*password: " { send "password\r" }
expect "*#" { send "exit\r" }
EOF
expect <<-EOF >> /home/file
set timeout 3 ip
spawn ssh -oPort=port ip  grep error /dir/dir/file
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "*password: " { send "password\r" }
expect "*#" { send "exit\r" }
EOF
expect <<-EOF >> /home/file
set timeout 3
spawn ssh -oPort=port ip grep error /dir/dir/file1
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "*password: " { send "password\r" }
expect "*#" { send "exit\r" }
EOF
```

Now have you may have noticed i connect to the machine 4 times, which feels so inefficient, i have tried to put all of this log searches into 1 ssh connection, like the following:

```
expect <<-EOF > /home/file
set timeout 3
spawn ssh -oPort=port ip zgrep "error" /dir/dir/file.gz.\[54321\]
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "*password: " { send "password\r" }
expect "*#" { send "grep error /dir/dir/file1\r" }
expect "*#" { send "exit\r" }
EOF
```

but when i try this i get the error

```
spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"expect "*#" { send "grep error /dir/dir/file1\r" }"
```

What is wrong with this code that make it output this error,
All help appreciated

Comment: why not just separate the commands on one line using `;` ?

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: `spawn ssh -oPort=port ip zgrep "error" /dir/dir/file.gz.\[54321\] ; zgrep "error" /dir/dir/file1.gz.\[54321\] ;  grep error /dir/dir/file ;  grep error /dir/dir/file1`

Comment: could you explain to me what this exactly does

Comment: `;` is simply a command separator. It runs each command consecutively. When one command completes it runs the next command after `;`

Comment: i get invalid command name "zgrep" while executing zgrep EBD /confdia/backup/error.cierrtef.log.gz.\[54321\]

Comment: You'll probably need to modify your quotation marks and escape characters for the shell not to interpret them. There is no need to wrap the string `error` in quotation marks. - `spawn ssh -oPort=port ip "zgrep error /dir/dir/file.gz.[54321] ; zgrep error /dir/dir/file1.gz.[54321] ; grep error /dir/dir/file ; grep error /dir/dir/file1"`

Comment: @alfred, you might want to post an answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single command to do all the work required in one expect session:

```
expect <<-EOF > /home/file
set timeout 3
spawn ssh -oPort=port ip "zgrep error /dir/dir/file.gz.[54321] ; zgrep error /dir/dir/file1.gz.[54321] ; grep error /dir/dir/file ; grep error /dir/dir/file1"
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "*password: " { send "password\r" }
expect "*#" { send "exit\r" }
EOF
```

You will need to modify your quotation `"` marks and escape characters `\` so that the remote shell does not to interpret them.  There is no need to wrap the string `error` in quotation marks.